# Cors error when making requests from frontend client

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

I have a fullstack application dockerized and deployed on a VPS with a custom domain, but there's an issue where requests I made on the frontend give me a Cors error like this.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://backend:8080/api/link/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

I normally use Create react app and it doesn't give me this error, but for this I'm using Vite and can't seem to find out what's causing it.

On my backend I've added the Springboot annotation to deal with the Cors error.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

and also disabled Cors in my security config.

On the frontend side, I added this which points to my backend (Docker service)

```
  "proxy": "http://backend:8080",
```

and this is my vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

I can make requests from Postman and it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to proxy the request
CORS requests will be blocked by the browser for security reasons To avoid this, the backend needs to inject allow origin header for you.

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api', {
        target: 'http://www.api.com',
        logLevel: 'debug',
        changeOrigin: true
    }));
};
```

or you can use the google chrome extension Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: Hey, I'm not using express for this project

Answer (score 0):

There are many suggestions online, i too have tried most of em.

1. Using `@CrossOrigin("URL")` over your controller class
2. Disabling cors via object of HttpSecurity, such as `http.cors().disable();`

Ultimately, i had to implement `WebMvcConfigurer` interface to resolve this issue.

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("URL");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I wouldn't suggest adding/disabling CORS in browser, plus it can be only managed by backend. Front-end has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I've tried it but still getting the same error

Comment: try adding `http.cors().and()` to your HttpSecurity instance after this config

Comment: I did but still doesn't work, switched back to CRA from vite and everthing works fine now . Thanks